# Firebase delete rewrite rule with source "**"

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I added a simple rewrite rule to my firebase config

```
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"}
    ],
```

And now I want to remove it and get back the default behaviour meaning that not all paths should load the index.html.

I tried removing that rule, all rewrites, removing the rewrite field but looks like the rewrite persists.

- If I go to myapp.web.app/something.html -> it renders index.html

I don't think its a cache issue because if I change the rule to have a different destination value it works immediately after `firebase deploy`.

If I do a preview deployment without the rules it works as expected (no rewrites) but then if I deploy prod again the old rule persists.

- If I go to myapp.web.app/something.html -> it renders something.html as I want

I tested this on multiple browsers and in incognito window.

I am using the frameworks feature with next.js, not sure if this affects the rewrites - I dont have any rewrites or redirects on next.config.js

Is there a way to reset the rewrite rules?

Comment: Please edit the question to be clear about what specifically isn't working the way you expect.  You can definitely change the rewrite rules, but we don't know what you're trying and observing when you say "all rewrites but no luck".  Be specific about what you are doing so that we can easily duplicate the same behavior you observe.

Comment: I added a bit more context. Basically I want to get the default behaviour back. Remove the rule that makes all paths load index.html.

Comment: Would you like to share what exactly you're doing to observe the behavior?  Share some URLs you tried and the results you observed, and also state what you expected to see instead of what you actually got.  Did you load them in a browser?  Did you use curl or some other HTTP tool to see the specifics of the request and response?  We should be able to duplicate the behavior using the instructions you provide.

Comment: The behaviour I want is myapp.web.app/something.html to render something.html - This was happening until I created the rewrite rule. Now it always renders index.html (or the page in the source field), even after I remove that rule. I tested in multiple browsers but I will test with curl.

Comment: Update: Curl return the contents of index.html even after I removed the rewrite rule.